# Projectors transparent texture unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been fiddling with Projectors and looking around the web to create a ground indicator like this
[image]
But I can't seem to understand or get the codes to work, what I'm really struggling with is with shader and it's languages :l and how to make it so that it will project a transparent texture onto the floor that can be moved around by an object.

I was hoping someone could guide or provide me a sample that could teach me afew things about what I need to do.

Thank you for helping!

[Video of what I want to achieve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AuE9nkuOUyI) (Just the projection)

Comment: +1 for league of legends brand picture :D. Unfortunately this question are off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: I didn't realize, I have been asking similar topics about unity but community here still helps me out :)